# How to sum UTC format and secs

Tags: db2

in my DB2 database, I have the UTC data in the format 1160307**14**4500000 and a field which indicates the time difference respect to local date, for example 3600 in seconds. 
I need sum to UTC date the 3600 secs so I can get 1160307**15**4500000.

Comment: Your math is wrong; `1160307144500000` appears to be in microseconds (1e^-6), so that plus 3600 seconds (one hour) would be `11603**107**44500000`.  Unless it's a CYYMMDD-formatted date, in which case you're screwed.  Well, not really, but you should have stored it as an actual timestamp if that's the case (probably should be anyways).  Why is the field supposedly in UTC but you're storing an additional field for an offset to somewhere else?  Which might change, especially twice a year?  Also, getting Unix-stamps is difficult in DB2, which might make querying problematic.

Comment: Actually, that looks like a "packed" version of `struct tm`:
116 = years since 1900; 03 = months since january and so on. This timestamp would decode as 2016-04-07T14:45:00.000

Answer (score 0):

Here is some DB2 code snippet

```
TIMESTAMP('1900-01-01 00:00:00') 
+ INT(SUBSTR(utc_data,1,3)) YEAR 
+ INT(SUBSTR(utc_data,4,2)) + 1 MONTH 
+ INT(SUBSTR(utc_data,6,2)) DAY 
+ INT(SUBSTR(utc_data,8,2))  HOUR 
+ INT(SUBSTR(utc_data,10,2)) MINUTE 
+ INT(SUBSTR(utc_data,12,2)) SECOND 
+ 1000*INT(SUBSTR(utc_data,15,3)) MICROSECOND 
+ diff_data SECOND
```

I'll leave the code to transform the timestamp back to the original format up to you :)